# jQuery conflict in rails application

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I am building an application with Ruby on Rails. I include in my Gemfile the following:

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.1.0'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '4.1.0'
```

which adds to my website:
jQuery JavaScript Library v1.11.0 and jQuery UI 1.10.3

I also use:

```
gem 'mercury-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury.git'
```

which adds to my website:

jQuery UI 1.8.13

Now when I try to make a list sortable there is a conflict with the loaded files and I get a TypeError: $.ui.contains is not a function

If I remove mercury everything works fine.

Is there a way I can organize my javascript files so that mercury.js is loaded only to specific pages (on which I don't use sortable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `yeild :javascripts` in your layout and in specific templates you could do a

```
content_for :javascripts do
  <script src='whatever'></scirpt>
end
```